# Pimcore ImportDefinitions set object id according to csv column name

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

What I want to do is save or show object name using my csv column name.

Here you can see in my Pim all the items (objects) arrange under relevant category.

[image]

But object show as a random name! eg- 5c494cc5cc271
Is there way to set this random name using my csv column?

Thanks,

Tharanga.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping you have to map a value from your csv file to "o_key" field.
[image]

You can also use "key" setter - it will ensure that key value is correct.